# Custom php file directory in Wordpress with Timber Twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, php-7, timber

I am using [Timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/) with Wordpress (version 5.4.2). I have installed Timber's [starter theme](https://timber.github.io/docs/getting-started/setup/#use-the-starter-theme) as a boilerplate.

Timber leverages the Wordpress template hierarchy allowing you to create a [custom PHP file for a given route](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/custom-page-templates/#custom-php-file).

**Page.php (default in Timber starter theme)**

```
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * To generate specific templates for your pages you can use:
 * /mytheme/templates/page-mypage.twig
 * (which will still route through this PHP file)
 * OR
 * /mytheme/page-mypage.php
 * **(in which case you'll want to duplicate this file and save to the above path)**
 *
 * Methods for TimberHelper can be found in the /lib sub-directory
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since    Timber 0.1
 */

$context = Timber::context();

$timber_post = new Timber\Post();

$context['post'] = $timber_post;

Timber::render( [ 'page-' . $timber_post->post_name . '.twig', 'page.twig' ], $context );
```

As per the comments in page.php and the Timber docs, I can create a custom PHP file to load a template for a given page by create it in the root directory of the theme (`mytheme/my-custom-php-file.php`)

But I will be creating a lot of custom PHP files for the project I'm working on - it would be pretty messy and hard to manage if I just drop them all into the root directory of the theme.

I would instead like to place these files into their own directory `mytheme/src/`. ex. `mytheme/src/my-custom-php-file.php`.

Currently, Timber/Wordpress will not recognize this file in this directory.

Where in Timber and/or Wordpress is the directory in which to look for pages' PHP files defined and how can I update this to indicate `mytheme/src/`?

Comment: Did you try this: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/template-locations/

Comment: I read that doc but it looks like this refers to the location of twig templates only, but not the respective php files

Comment: Timber uses WordPress's template hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page. You may want to check this out: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/

Comment: Ah, I see. If you are using their starter theme, then I think the only way to do that is to modify `index.php` to include your conditions, but it could get messy really fast, unless your pages/posts follow a pattern. For instance, if they are CPTs you can do something like `if(is_singular('news')){/*Logic here*/}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, but a little differently than you might expect. You have to put **all theme-related files to a subfolder**, including **functions.php** and **style.css**. WordPress recognizes themes in subfolders.

So here’s what a possible structure could look like:

```
.
└── wp-content/themes/mytheme/
    ├── theme/
    │   ├── functions.php
    │   ├── index.php
    │   ├── page.php
    │   ├── single.php
    │   └── style.css
    ├── vendor/
    ├── views/
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── composer.json
    ├── package.json
    └── README.md
```

We’re putting the template files that WordPress needs into a **theme** subfolder. You can still put your **views** folder in the theme root, because Timber also looks for Twig templates in that folder.

In your **functions.php** file, you would then require your Composer dependencies from the parent folder:

```php
require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And there might be some other places where you would have to update paths.

We’re currently thinking about making this the default for the [Timber Starter Theme](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme) (see [this pull request](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme/pull/103)).

Comment: this worked! thanks so much!! and thank you for the shout out in the PR

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the `template_include` docs for I think you might be able to do something like this:

```
// functions.php
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    return 'src/' . $template;
}, 99 );
```

OR

```
// functions.php
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if (// some condition) {
        return 'src/' . $template;
    }
    
    return $template;
}, 99 );
```

Comment: this is halfway there - I had to define `$template` in the callback function to set the correct path like this: `$template = str_replace('themes/mytheme/', 'themes/mytheme/src/', $template);` since `$template` seems to return the full path to the file. But now, my php file needs to be in *both* places (mytheme/ and /mytheme/src/) for it to load correctly. If I remove the php file from the theme root, Wordpress looks for `index.php` as per the hierarchy, but if I remove php file from `src/` nothing loads (no error but white page) - only file in _both_ places loads correct content

Comment: Magling `template_include` is the bad way. Please consider the answer of @gchtr